# After adding google_mobile_ads, firebase_admob or admob_flutter packages to my project, the emulator cant open the project

Tags: flutter, dart, package, ads, pubspec

I tried adding google_mobile_ads, firebase_admob and admob_flutter packages to my project to add ads to my app.
But after every package the emulator stopped working without any error.

I tried to change the minSdkVersion to 21. Not working.
Tried minifyEnabled. Still not working.

Just to be sure that the problem was due to the change in the yaml file, I held the other files stable and changed only the yaml file. The problem is obviously from the packages imo.

So I'm open to suggestions of any kind. Thx in advance. (Package suggestions are also welcomed)

P.S.: I'm a newbee. Go easy on me.

Comment: welcome @mehmetduygu. Please share your code snippet, .yaml file and gradle codes to enable community members reproducing it

Answer (score 0):

After adding a lot of packages, I realized that I had to set multidex to true and add the app level gradle file the following line to dependencies: - implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

The other problem was with the gradle files. The gradle files didn't have the required modifications.

So I add the following to project level gradle file:

- classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

Then I updated minSdkVersion in app level gradle file (with 21) and added the following line: - implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'

And viola!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `minSdkVersion` in your `android/app/build.gradle` file to at least 21 also fixes this ([see Flutter Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support)).